# Laravel query whereIn - show results from which search

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have an array that comes to controller's action.

```
$arrOfTags = $request['position'];
```

That array looks like :

```
['manager', 'consultant'];
```

Next, I am querying the DB for CV's where position is one of these.

```
$query = Cv::query();
$query->whereIn('position', $arrOfTags);
...
->get();
```

Now the question : 
If `$request['position'] = ['manager','consultant'];` and `whereIn` clause finds result just for `position = 'consultant'` and none for `'manager'`, how can I programmatically discover that results are found for `'consultant'` and/or didn't found for `'manager'` ?

EDIT

All my query's code :

```
$arrOfTags = explode(',', $request['position']);
$query = Cv::query();
        $query->whereIn('position', $arrOfTags)
 if($request['salary']) {
            $query->whereIn('salary', $request['salary']);
        }

        if($request['skill']) {
            $query->join('skills', 'cvs.id', '=', 'skills.cv_id')
                  ->join('allskills', 'skills.allskills_id', '=', 'allskills.id')
                  ->select('cvs.*', 'allskills.name AS skillName')
                  ->whereIn('skills.allskills_id', $request['skill']);
        }

        if($request['language']) {
            $query->join('languages', 'cvs.id', '=', 'languages.cv_id')
                  ->join('alllanguages', 'languages.alllanguages_id', '=', 'alllanguages.id')
                  ->select('cvs.*', 'alllanguages.name as languageName')
                  ->whereIn('languages.alllanguages_id', $request['language']);
        }

        $cvs = $query->distinct()->get();
```

> Imagine that $arrOfTags values are `['manager', 'consultant', 'sales']`
>
> I want somehow to discover that results was found for `position =`
>   `manager and consultant`, and didn't found for `position = 'sales'`

Comment: You can get the position data from your query result or below answer is the perfect one to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the data from DB:

```
$cvs = CV::....;
```

And then use the [`partition()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-partition) method:

```
list($manager, $consultant) = $cvs->partition(function ($i) {
    return $i['position'] === 'manager';
});
```

Or the [`where()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-where) method:

```
$manager = $cvs->where('position', 'manager');
$consultant = $cvs->where('position', 'consultant');
```

Both `partition()` and `where()` will not execute any additional queries to DB.

Comment: That's the way. I am doing a big query.
$query = Cv::query();
$query->whereIn('position', $arrOfTags);
then I verify if isset $request['age'] , if yes, add smth like 
$query->where('age' < 19) 
and after 10 steps of checking requests for each filter's name, I am making a 
-get();  results.

So, is there a way how after query become long enough with 4-5 conditions, inclusive joins, to discover that results from position = manager was not found?

Comment: @priMo-ex3m you can use `where('postition', 'sales')->isEmpty()` if you just want to know if there are any results for `sales`

Comment: Ok, but I need it to not have static) This array is always different, and I need to determine always dynamic it all. Probably using for cycle with code you write below? And foreach is empty, add some semi-hardcoded text with found/not found?


Ok, but if I have a list of skills, that is double-related, and I want to determine witch of them are not found, how can did it ?

Comment: @priMo-ex3m I honestly don't understand what are you talking about. You're getting the data first. And then you just work with loaded data (Laravel collection). You can safely check if this collection has some data or not.

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way too:

```
$managers = $collection->search(function ($item, $key) {
  return $item['position'] === "manager";
});

$consultants = $collection->search(function ($item, $key) {
  return $$item['position'] === "consultant";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [count()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#retrieving-single-models).

```
if(($query->count)==($query->where('position','consultant')->count())){
      ///all are coming for position=consultants
}
```

Or you could use `groupBY`-

```
$query = $query->groupBy('position')->toArray();
```

And `retrieve` by-

```
$consultants = $query['consultant'];
```